# firing query / javascript functions in the right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This is a simple question, but one i've only seen answered with complex specific examples.

I want to run three functions in order, one after the previous one has finished.

```
f1();
f2();
f3();
```

I'm really struggling to do in javascript(/jquery)?! even if i define f1 as:

```
function f1(){
f1s normal code;
f2();
}
```

it will still start f2 before f1 has finished its work. I've tried .whens and .done or .thens. I've tried making callback functions with some success. but if someone could cleanly answer this simple example it would help me so much to understand.
thanks in advance!

Comment: It will not.... there is no parallel programming with `js`.

Comment: Unless those do something asynchronous, they will run in order. Even if they do something asynchronous, they will run in order, it just might not seem like it.

Comment: I'd suggest that because JavaScript is single-threaded it *should* (so far as I've ever been able to tell) work linearly through the functions as they're found/parsed in the document/script. So it should certainly *not* execute `f2()` before 'finishing' `f1()`.

Comment: If they *are* doing something asynchronous, the asynch call should have a callback function that fires when it's done.

Comment: @JamesAllardice. well worded!

Comment: the problem is most likely to do with what your functions actually *do*;  please show us actual code that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: If _normal_ _code_ triggers some events, there might be event handlers calling other functions before f1 has finished.

Answer (score 2):

as long as there is no asynchronous code running in the bodies of the 3 methods, they will always run in order. if you have asynchronous code (ie ajax calls) then you will want to use callback methods.

Comment: thanks (everyone). they do include some ajax calls, they also include some animations (which I think also can run on another thread....??) so I might clean up my code to use those callback functions. I guess the functions that have callbacks have them for a reason, like .animate and .post... thanks again. I'd +1 you but obviously i lack the reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks, maybe this helps?

http://jsfiddle.net/2heHs/

Also look at: https://github.com/leesherwood/jquery-function-stack

This is something i chucked up on github. Its not really intended for everyone to use just yet as i mainly needed it for a private project. But if you can make sense of it then feel free to use it. I will be making it cleaner and adding a lot more stuff too it when i get time. Of course you need to be using jquery to use it.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is, by nature, single threaded and sequential. the only way around this is ajax and html5 workers.

that being said, if you want to run three separate functions in order, javascript does that by nature:

```
var func1 = function () {
    console.log('func1 ran');
};
var func2 = function () {
    console.log('func2 ran');
};
var func3 = function () {
    console.log('func3 ran');
};

// run them in order
func1();
func2();
func3();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/cxxLY/